# Ativar e desativar botão em php

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho este botão para editar que está sempre disponível para edição:

```
<a type="button" name="edit3" id="'.$row["Id"].','.$row["IdConsulta"].'" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal3" class="btn btn-primary edit_data3">Editar</a>
```

Pretendia que ficasse ativo só no momento que é feito um novo registo na tabela da base de dados e à meia noite desse mesmo dia voltasse a ficar desativo, e no momento que fica ativo só permitisse editar o novo registo inserido, nos registos antigos que é possível consultar continuava aparecer desativo ou oculto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei uma variável com a data atual que compara com a data do registo. Criei uma variável disabled vazia. Coloco essa variável disabled no link. Se a data for diferente da data atual coloca a variável disabled preenchida

```
<?php
$dataAtual = DATE('Y-m-d');
$disabled = "";

if(DATE($row['Data2'])!=$dataAtual){
$disabled = "disabled";
?>

<a type="button" name="edit3" id="'.$row["Id"].','.$row["IdConsulta"].'" data-toggle="modal" href="#add_data_Modal3" class="btn btn-primary edit_data3" '.$disabled.'>Editar</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

São muitas questões em uma única pergunta, então vamos separá-las em partes (**"Dividir para Conquistar"**):

Quanto à questão de ativar o botão, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
//para desabilitar o botão
$('.edit_data3').prop("disabled",true);

//para habilitar o botão
$('.edit_data3').prop("disabled",false);
```

Quanto as outras questões, podem ser resolvidas de várias formas (**que irei fazer genericamente**):

```
function minhafuncao(){
  var dataHora = Date.now();
  var meiaNoite = 23:59;

  if(novoRegistro && dataHora < meiaNoite){
    $('.edit_data3').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('.edit_data3').prop("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

agora é só você ficar chamando essa função várias vezes.

Comment: coloquei o script com a função dentro do `head` e chamo-a no botão da seguinte forma `onclick="minhafuncao()"` mas recebo este erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: novoRegistro is not defined`

Comment: pode só explicar a que se refere o `novoRegistro`?

Comment: a variável novoRegistro seria um booleano que seria retornado de alguma função que verifica se foi adicionado algum novo registro.

Comment: ok, tenho de ver como criar essa função para fazer essa verificação. Nunca criei

Comment: pode ajudar a criar essa função para verificar se foi adicionado o novo registo? Não estou a conseguir

Comment: a função para verificar se houve novo registo, pode ser a função que está no success do Ajax?

Comment: ainda não consegui resolver este problema que coloquei nesta pergunta, poderá ajudar me aplicar a sua solução?